# GoogleMap не отображается кнопка текущего местоположения

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Добавил во фрагмент карту, добавил интерфейсы, которые отвечают за местоположение, но кнопка определения местоположения так и не появилась.

Код:

```
public class FragmentMapsShop extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
    private GoogleMap map;
    MapView mapView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Карта");
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mapView != null) {
            mapView.onCreate(null);
            mapView.onResume();
            mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);

        UiSettings mapUiSetting = map.getUiSettings();

        mapUiSetting.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        //mapUiSetting.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //mapUiSetting.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); 
        mapUiSetting.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        LatLng shop = new LatLng(55.805, 37.636);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(shop).title("Shop"));
//        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(shop));
        CameraPosition liberty = CameraPosition.builder().target(shop).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(liberty));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "MyLocation button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationClick(@NonNull Location location) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Текущее положение\n" + location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: в манифесте добавил разрешения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**fragment_shop_map.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myLocationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

**FragmentMapsShop:**

```
private void userLocationFAB(){
        FloatingActionButton FAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.myLocationButton);
        FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mapView.getMyLocation() != null) { // Check to ensure coordinates aren't null, probably a better way of doing this...
                    mapView.setCenterCoordinate(new LatLngZoom(mapView.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mapView.getMyLocation().getLongitude(), 20), true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

В методе `onCreate`, внутри `FragmentMapsShop` добавьте `mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

*update:*

Добавьте перед `mapUiSetting.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true)` -

```
.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

**example**:

```
    mapUiSetting.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mapUiSetting.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mapUiSetting.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

p.s. `myLocationButtonEnabled` по умолчанию `true` и отображается когда `setMyLocationEnabled` `true`.
```

**Update**

```
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            return;
        }
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMyLocationClickListener(this);

        UiSettings mapUiSetting = map.getUiSettings();

        mapUiSetting.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
//        mapUiSetting.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mapUiSetting.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        LatLng shop = new LatLng(55.805, 37.636);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(shop).title("Shop"));
        CameraPosition liberty = CameraPosition.builder().target(shop).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(liberty));
```

Comment: Этот способ конечно работает, но мне хочется использовать стандартный способ, который описан в этой статье, но у меня не работает

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location?hl=ru

Comment: Добавил возможное решение вашей проблемы

Comment: я же добавил, оно в условии прописано

Comment: mapUiSetting.mapUiSetting(true); вы не ошиблись?

Comment: опечатка, да. поправил.

Comment: а в if у вас заходит?

Comment: я обновил весь код. Не видит этот метод mapUiSetting.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: .getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: если это к MapUiSetting, то нет. Может это из-за того что это фрагмент, а не активити?

Comment: а вы можете обновить код, вы написали что-то переписали

Comment: mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(this);
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: у меня вот так все работает

Comment: кнопка появилась, а на эмуляторе же он не определит текущее местоположени?

Comment: Неа, дефолтное нужно указывать или где то в настройках эмулятора

Comment: кнопка появилась после чего? что сделали то?

Comment: ваш код вставил, ток удалил setOnCameraMovieListener(this). Сейчас добавлю текущий код

Comment: Кажется я понял, раньше я помещал map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); в условие, теперь я его поместил за условием

Comment: я же вас спросил еще "а в if у вас заходит? "

Comment: Походу я не увидел) Извини